# Dividing a SplitArrayField in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-forms

in my Django form I´m using a SplitArrayField to create a matrix of integers and it works like a charm when getting all the values and processing them.

```
class SimplexForm(Form):
    CHOICES = [('Maximizar', 'Maximizar'),
               ('Minimizar', 'Minimizar')]
    tipo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label="Tipo de función")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        variables = kwargs.pop('variables')
        restricciones = kwargs.pop('restricciones')
        super(SimplexForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["funcion"] = SplitArrayField(forms.IntegerField(),size=variables, label="Función objetivo")
        self.fields["restricciones"] = SplitArrayField(SplitArrayField(forms.IntegerField(),size=variables+1,label="Restriccion"),size=restricciones,label="Restricciones")
```

My problem is that when the fields are rendered all of them are displayed in a line.

I´ve already tried this way but without results:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ formulario.restricciones.errors }}
    <label for="{{ formulario.restricciones.id_for_label }}">Restricciones:</label>
    {% for campo in formulario.restricciones %}
          <p> {{ campo }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This is how it´s currently displayed:

[SplitArrayField in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLa36.png)

So is there a way I can split that train of fields with Django template?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `<br />` after each `<p>` tag in the for loop?

Comment: It just adds an empty space after the whole section unfortunately

Comment: Weird! No `display: inline` on the `p` tags in your CSS reset or anything?

Comment: The thing is that if I leave the template as a plain form.as_p I get the same results so it´s a problem with the way Django renders the SplitArrayField